# DevOps Pipeline does not update pods

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I have a AKS infrastructure where I deploy my projects using DevOps pipeline.

Unfortunately my procedure is:

1. Delete pods manually
2. Run pipeline

There is no better way?

My pipeline is:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  - repo: self
pr:
  - develop

variables:
  *

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build Stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
          - task: Maven@3
          - task: Docker@2
          - upload: manifests
            artifact: manifests
  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy stage
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy
        workspace:
          clean: all
        pool: Default
        environment: $(clusterEnv)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: KubernetesManifest@0
                  displayName: Deploy to kubernetes cluster
                  inputs:
                    action: deploy
                    namespace: $(k8sNamespace)
                    kubernetesServiceConnection: $(kubernetesServiceConnection)
                    manifests: |
                      $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/myManifest.yml
                    containers: $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepo):latest
```

Do I have something wrong at deploy stage? or forgeting something?

thks

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is the effect of using the latest tag.

Kubernetes doesn't see a change to the manifest, it doesn't know that the image with the latest tag has changed...

If it doesn't think the deployment from the manifest is different then the pods will not be recreated.

It's generally bad practice to use latest, so I'd suggest moving away from that... which in turn resolves your problem.